# Principal Axis Maximization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I know that, in order to use `PrincipalAxis`, for example in `FindMaximum` function:

```
FindMaximum[
 f[x,y], {{x,x0,x1},{y,y0,y1}}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
```

You have to provide two initial points, for each argument.
However, `PrincipalAxis` also seems to work when just one initial point is given. Do you know what actually *Mathematica* does in such a case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The starting point is [the Principal Axis Method tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationPrincipalAxisMethod.html):

> For an $n$-variable problem, take a set of search directions
>   $u_1,u_2,...,u_n$ and a point $x_0$. Take $x_i$ to be the point that
>   minimizes $f$ along the direction $u_i$ from $x_{i-1}$ (i.e. do a line
>   search from  $x_{i-1}$), then replace $u_i$ with $u_{i+1}$.
>
> Two distinct starting conditions in each variable are required for
>   this method because these are used to define the magnitudes of the
>   vectors $u_i$.

I think that the first parameter is the starting point, $x_0$, and, combined with the second parameter, both define the magnitude of the search direction.

One can start to delve into the behaviour using `EvaluationMonitor`. First, using a single parameter of 0.5, the search is quite close to the initial starting point of 0.5.

```
FindMinimum[x^2, {{x, 0.5}}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis",
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print["x = ", x]]
(* x = 0.5
   x = 0.484
   x = 0.474
   x = 0.407
   x = 5.8e-15
   ... *)
```

I think, for the case of the second parameter, not specifying it is the same as setting it to zero, since

```
FindMinimum[x^2, {{x, 0.5, 0}}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis", 
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print["x = ", x]]
```

gives the same behaviour as above.

Compare with specifying a huge second parameter, where the search initially jumps a long way from the starting point.

```
FindMinimum[x^2, {{x, 0.5, 10000}}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis",
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print["x = ", x]]
(* x = 0.5
   x = 312.984
   x = -192.626
   x = 119.858
   x = -73.276
   x = 3.2e-15
   ... *)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Indeed, it seems that the second parameter is treated as zero. However, it also works if your only parameter is (starting point) 0.