# FindMinimum step size too small

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I'm running a simulation of an electromagnetic system using Radia, an external code that is run from Mathematica. I want to use `FindMinimum` to determine some optimum parameters for this simulation. So my function definition is something like:

```
totalFPandRMSXZ[eps1_?NumericQ, eps2_?NumericQ, eps3_?NumericQ, 
                ebs1_?NumericQ, ebs2_?NumericQ] := 
    Total@(Flatten[finalPosAndRMSXP[eps1, eps2, eps3, ebs1, ebs2]][[2, 6, 9, 11, 13, 14]])^2
```

where `finalPosAndRMSXP` builds a structure, solves it and evaluates it.

So I use `FindMinimum` to look for the best values for the variables `ebs1` and `ebs2` (eventually I'll extend to all five variables).

```
FindMinimum[totalFPandRMSXZ[0, 0, 0, ebs1, ebs2], {ebs1, 8, 7}, {ebs2, 6, 6.5}, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
```

This is slow to run, so I don't want too many function calls. And this will be a real thing that gets built, so I only want to find an answer for the best value of `ebs1` and `ebs2` to one decimal place. (These are dimensions in mm.) There may be a difference between 8.000 and 8.001, but I'm not interested in it. But when I execute the `FindMinimum`, I get function calls with parameters:

```
{0,0,0,8.,6.}
{0,0,0,7.96875,6.}
{0,0,0,8.01931,6.}
{0,0,0,8.01914,6.}
{0,0,0,8.01183,6.}
{0,0,0,8.01635,6.}
{0,0,0,8.01807,6.}
{0,0,0,8.01873,6.}
{0,0,0,8.01848,6.}
{0,0,0,8.01887,6.}
```

How can I tell Mathematica to take bigger steps?

Answer (score 2):

I can only say about `Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"` with which I have experience. This method uses the `"TrustRegion"` line search method which current implementation in *Mathematica* has a very significant shortcoming which I described in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116295/280) of mine. The essence of the problem seems to be that `FindMinimum` doesn't increase step size when it should. The option `"AcceptableStepRatio"` in such situations seemingly doesn't work: setting `"AcceptableStepRatio" -> 10^-100` along with `"MaxScaledStepSize" -> Infinity` changes nothing.

The only way to overcome this limitation is to introduce the concept of `FindMinimum` sessions: when the step size becomes too small you finish current session and start a new `FindMinimum` session with parameters obtained during previous session. In this new session `FindMinimum` will start from the `"StartingScaledStepSize"` again and as a result will achieve the minimum MUCH faster than if you allow it to continue previous session. From my experience in some situations this approach allows to achieve the minimum 10 - 20 times faster than the default.

The main rule of thumb is as follows: if the process of minimization takes more than 100 iterations (in some cases may be 300 iterations but it is undoubtedly so for 1000 iterations) then at the end the step size becomes so small that the process of minimization becomes very slow. So usually I simply set `MaxIterations -> 100` and restart `FindMinimum` with parameters obtained on previous step until it reaches the minimum. In such a way I get the minimum in, say, 2000 iterations while when I simply set `MaxIterations -> 10000` I get the same (or worse) minimum in, say, 8000 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

From `FindMinimum`'s point of view, the objective function you are minimizing is a "black-box function", meaning it is an oracle, that yields values, but not derivatives, or Hessians.

If the method chosen by `FindMinimum` to solve the problem requires a gradient of the objective function at a point, finite differences are used to approximate it.

The multitude of evaluations at 'too-precise' points come from that, and the arguments are indeed different, just beyond the printing accuracy.

The solution is to use a minimization method that is derivative-free, and since your problem is unconstrained, you can use `Method -> "PrincipalAxis"`.

Comment: I thought Principal Axis was the default method when you provide two starting values?

Answer (score 0):

Referring back to [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109719/principal-axis-maximization) regarding the `"PrincipalAxis"` method, and the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationPrincipalAxisMethod.html):

> For an $n$-variable problem, take a set of search directions
>   $u_1,u_2,...,u_n$ and a point $x_0$. Take $x_i$ to be the point that
>   minimizes $f$ along the direction $u_i$ from $x_{i-1}$ (i.e. do a line
>   search from  $x_{i-1}$), then replace $u_i$ with $u_{i+1}$.
>
> Two distinct starting conditions in each variable are required for
>   this method because these are used to define the magnitudes of the
>   vectors $u_i$.

I think that the first parameter is the starting point, $x_0$, and, combined with the second parameter, thus define the magnitude of the search direction.

I suggest playing around with the magnitude of the second parameter, in that case, and perhaps using `EvaluationMonitor[]` to investigate the behaviour.

```
FindMinimum[x^2, {{x, 0.5}}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis",
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print["x = ", x]]
```